# fields are not being added into a table

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel, I have an assingee table where most of the information should be stored I have added tow new additional fields which are not being added to the table for some reason.

here my is create.blade.index:

```
     <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Entry Type:</strong>
            <select name="entrytype" class="form-control">
                              <option value="EEF">EEF</option>
                              <option value="TEP">TEP</option>
                              <option value="Email">Email Approval</option>
                              <option value="Incident">Incident</option>
                            </select>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Referance id:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="refnumber" class="form-control" placeholder="RFC or EEF Number">
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Cabinet name:</strong>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cabinet" placeholder="Cabinet Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Notes:</strong>
            <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Notes">
        </div>
```

refine and cabinet name are being added successfully into the database but 'notes' and entry type are not being stored into the request/sent to the database.
here my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $timestamp = now();

        $request->merge(["timein"=>$timestamp]);
        $request->merge(["timeout"=>' ']);

        $request->validate([
          'cabinet' => 'required',
          'notes' => 'required',
          'entrytype' => 'required',
          'timein' => 'required',
          'timeout' => 'nullable',
          'refnumber' => 'required',
          'custidno' => 'required',
          'cardno' => 'required',

          ]);

          assignee::create($request->all());

          return redirect()->route('assignees.index')
                          ->with('success','assignee created successfully.');
      }
```

I am not sure why notes and entry type are not being saved, I have followed the exact steps for all the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you put those values in your fillable array in your model:

Should look like this:

```
protected fillable = ['cabinet', 'notes', 'entrytype', 'timein', 'timeout', 'refnumber', 'custidno', 'cardno'];
```

If that still does not work return this in your method:

```
dd($request->all());
```

To actually check what you are sending.

If that does not return all data you are missing something in your form or migration.

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about the fillable array!